# Why are my media queries not applying correctly?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries, styled-components

Only the last declared media query is being applied, regardless of the screen size. In the example component below, the color is always green, even when the screen width is 320px.

Breakpoints:

```
const size = {
    mobileM: '400px',
    mobileL: '480px',
    tablet: '760px',
    laptop: '1280px', 
    desktopM: '1530px',
    desktopL: '1920px',
};

export const devices = {
    mobileM: `(min-width: ${size.mobileM})`,
    mobileL: `(min-width: ${size.mobileL})`,
    tablet: `(min-width: ${size.tablet})`,
    laptop: `(min-width: ${size.laptop})`,
    desktopM: `(min-width: ${size.desktopM})`,
    desktopL: `(min-width: ${size.desktopL})`
};
```

Example component:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { devices } from '../utils/breakpoints';

function Welcome() {
  return (<>
    <HeaderMessage>Welcome</HeaderMessage>
    <BodyText>
      This questionnaire is used to help us understand your business goals and needs and guide us to create the best solution for you. 
    </BodyText>
    
    <BodyText>
      Please be as specific as possible in your answers as it will give us the most insight and enable us to help you best. 
    </BodyText>
    
    <BodyText>
      Use the back arrow in the top left corner at any time to navigate to a previous page to amend your answers.
    </BodyText>

  </>)
}

// font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
// font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

const HeaderMessage = styled.h1`
  color: #BA3D9C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: .5rem;
  margin-top: -13vw;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  @media ${devices.mobileM} {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: turquoise;
  }
  
  @media ${devices.mobileL} {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  @media ${devices.tablet}{
    color: green;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
`;
```

In the above component, the color is always green, even when the screen width is 320px.

Comment: I am not a preprocessor. What is the output? It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/media-queries-wwzpnd

Comment: It seems to work fine in the sandbox, but in my local only the last media query is being applied. Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine locally for me.

Comment: Can you use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied.

Comment: It works find in Firefox for me. It appears the issue is only in Chrome. I'm using styled-components, so it should be automatically adding vendor prefixes.

Comment: Here is a screenshot with dev tools. As you can see, even though the width is 480px, the styles for 760px media query are being applied. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GaEsKWyQDpFSKSCbbJK2gD0FGUVsL47V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After coming across this article and testing it https://medium.com/developer-rants/chrome-engines-ignoring-css-media-queries-ffee25f410fd I believe the issue was that I didn't add a viewport meta tag in the html doc so Chrome was ignoring my media queries, whereas Firefox wasn't. Now that I've added it, the media queries are working. However, the styling needs to be redone as the sizing is out of proportion. Out of the frying pan and into the fire 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Chrome was ignoring my media queries but Firefox wasn't was because I was missing the viewport meta tag in the head of my HTML file `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`. Without this, Chrome was ignoring my media queries.